# Can we check invalid file upload using TestCafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have an application where it accepts jpeg, png but not html files.
Using `await t.setFilesToUpload();` but it's passing for html files aswell!!!

Is there a way to test the invalid file formats?

Comment: I suppose you get some warning or something in the app changes when you try to upload a .html file. You need to assert that, not the upload itself.

Comment: There is no warning message , the only thing is I cant  see the uploaded html file(image) on the UI  but can see it in the DOM. I have tried using ( visibilityCheck: true).notOk() in the assert but it didn't help.

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to imagine how your app works. But I'm sure `t.setFilesToUpload()` won't check anything for you, so it will sets files to upload no matter what their extension is.

Comment: In the app when we browse to upload the files it disables the html files so that they cant be selected. Because we  cant test using native upload dialogue I cant test that way .So the only option I found is `t.setFilesToUpload()' which apparently doesn’t  validate the extensions.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure. It looks like you have some kind of client validation (probably the "accept" attribute). In this case, the `setFilesToUpload` method does not consider this type of validation.